# How to use ScriptingBridge to tell Safari to open a URL in a new window?

Tags: scripting-bridge

I have an Objective-C app that uses ScriptingBridge to control Safari.  It works, but I'm having trouble writing code for a new capability - to tell Safari to open a URL in a new window.  Here's the AppleScript that does what I want:

```
tell application "Safari"
make new document at end of documents
set URL of document 1 to "http://www.apple.com/"
end tell
```

and here's what I hoped to be the equivalent code using ScriptingBridge:

```
NSString *appName = @"com.apple.Safari";
safariApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:appName];

SafariDocument *doc = [[[safariApp classForScriptingClass:@"document"] alloc] init];
[[safariApp documents] addObject:doc];
doc.path = @"http://www.ford.com";
```

When I execute the latter code, Safari opens a new window, but the window shows my home page, not www.ford.com.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
NSDictionary *theProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"http://www.ford.com" forKey:@"URL"];
SafariDocument *doc = [[[safariApp classForScriptingClass:@"document"] alloc] initWithProperties:theProperties];
[[safariApp documents] addObject:doc];
[doc release];
```